# White bars on both sides of the image

Tags: html, css, image, margin

I am working on a website, but I have an issue with white bars on the side of my image.

I tried to fix that with margin, but they are still there.

Here is the code:

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #1A1A1A;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: -10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #36A9E0;
  color: #000;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.navbar .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .navbar.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .navbar.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

.footer {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: -10px;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-top: -4px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="fr">

<head>
  <title>Wolftime</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" href="img/logo.png">

<body>
  <div class="navbar" id="myNavbar">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="news.html">Actualités</a>
    <a href="team.html">Joueurs</a>
    <a href="video.html">Vidéos</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contacter</a>
    <a href="about.html">A propos</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <img src="http://edeboer.free.fr/img/1.png" width="100%">
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p class="legal">
      © 2018 Wolftime Entertainment. All Rights Reserved. The Wolftime logo and Wolftime.tk are trademarks of Wolftime Entertainment in FR and/or other countries.
    </p>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myNavbar");
      if (x.className === "navbar") {
        x.className += " responsive";
      } else {
        x.className = "navbar";
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried changing the margin to 0; on the body element in your CSS?

I just did it in the codepen and it worked.

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to fully see the impact of the default styling given the example, but the issue is visible in the code snippet.

You image does not have white bars. Your image has a fixed aspect ratio within the html page body.

The content of the page has padding. Your `nav` element is stacked at the top of the page and has `margin: -10px`. As the page has a natural padding you've "overridden" the built-in style.

The image is stacked correctly within the confines of a padded body. Removing the negative margin will realign the header to your image left and right edges.

Check any unwanted margins within parent elements of your image - including the `html` and `body` tags.